# Get form authentification cookie from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, forms, cookies

I'm creating some dynamic pictures with the IHttpHandler interface. Then I wont to create a pdf document, where those pictures are included.

But I need to copy the authentication cookie to my new HttpWebRequest object.

How can this be achieved?

I use normal asp.net forms.

Answer (score 1):

**You don't need to copy the Formauthentication cookie** and write it again in `HttpWebRequest` within the `HttpHandler` if the handler is served from the same domain. The cookie is already available within HttpWebRequest in the handler.

Comment: My problem is that my PDF component is making a new request, so I need the cookie. As it is now, my pictures is show as the login box :(

Comment: Can you please explain your situation with more details ? Cookies on one domain are accessible any path on the domain. Is your PDF handler on some other domain ?

Comment: I'm on the same domain. The problem is that my PDF component is reading the site in a new session. So to read the dynamic pictures I need the form authentication cookie. Hopes it makes it a bit more clear?